# how can i add setinterval function inside React new array state

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-state

I want to change with settimeout popup state true to false after onclick and settimeout.
when i click specific li , settodos fun and setTimeout function want to work.

```
const deleteHandle = () => {
  settodos(
    todos.map((item2) => {
      
        setTimeout(() => {
      if (item2.id === todo.id) {
        return {
          ...item2,
                        
            popup:!item2.popup,
            
          };
        }
      }, 200);
        // popup:!item2.popup
      return item2;
    })
  ); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` return the [timeoutID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#return_value), and not the value of the input function; also `map` method is [synchronous](https://medium.com/@nyablk97/array-map-async-await-160b66f7180e) and therefore will not wait for async functions, so this will not work the way you want. You should move the setTimeout out of the settodos, ex:

```
setTimout(()=>settodos(*your values*), 200)
```

Comment: dafault boolean is false and 
when I click it changed true and i want to
change back false after 2s

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I solved the problem now. I copied settodo function inside settimeout function manually  and change the default boolean value.